# Read from a text file and post the first 50 lines into another text file?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a text file and it is called 'Store.txt'.
I would like to know how I can read from this file and then grab the first 50 lines of numbers/text
and insert them into another text file.

I have little code because I'm not exactly sure how to go about it and I've been searching online but couldn't find much I believe an if statment is the answer?

Any way I have gave it ago but sadly it hasn't worked.
Here is how I got on-

```
<?php 
$fileToOpen = fopen('Store.txt', 'r');
$return = '';
$count = 0;

$return. = $fileToOpen. "\n";
    if ($count >= 50)
        break;
}

file_put_contents($return, "Store2nd.txt");
fclose($fileToOpen);
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help. (:

Comment: what does `store.txt`'s contents look like anyway?

Comment: How is that relevant?

Comment: @ziGi If OP said "first 50 lines" and nothing else, it wouldn't be relevant, but OP said "first 50 lines of numbers/text" - now it sounds like the content and its selection matters.

Comment: @ziGi what if it looks like a csv format? wouldn't you want to get the first 50 lines instead of straight up truncating 50 characters? might as well use `file()` then cut the array

Comment: its just a few lines of numbers and some text.

Comment: The text file "store.txt" has numbers in it that are sorted highest to lowest by another php file already but all this question/code should do is pull the "top" 50 lines (they will already be sorted).. :) and I'm looking for 50 lines not 50 characters of text, hopefully this isn't to much of a pain.

Comment: @Ravvvennna you can try out some answers below, its either you loop it and use a counter or load it all into an array and cut it. all the ideas are below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will copy upto the first 50 lines without reading in the complete file:

```
<?php

$fileToOpen = fopen('Store.txt', 'r');
$outputFile = fopen('Store2nd.txt', 'w');

$count = 0;
while (!feof($fileToOpen)) {  // We'll copy the whole file ...
    if ($count++ >= 50)       // ... or the first 50 lines, whichever is less
        break;
    $line = fgets($fileToOpen);
    fwrite($outputFile, $line);
}

fclose($fileToOpen);
fclose($outputFile);

?>
```

Comment: Trying and testing now thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
<?php 
$lines = file('Store.txt'); // make file content an array
$result = array_slice($lines,0,50); // take the first 50 lines
file_put_contents('Store2nd.txt', implode('', $result)); // output
?>
```

Comment: `implode("\n"`, just `implode(""` - elements of array already have new line symbols at the end. From manual of `file` function - `Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.`

Comment: I seem to be getting this Warning: file_put_contents( 14 - Score Name: Dragonic 14 - Score Name: Dragonic 9 - Score Name: Dragonic ) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: File name too long in /home/u146764286/public_html/BearSmash/Won3.php on line 4

Comment: Sorry, copied your solution and didn't check. File name should be the first parameter of `file_put_contents()` and content should be the second. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would probably be to do a foreach loop for your text.

Then add `$count++` in your loop so that the `$count = 0;` you've set up will increase.

Right now with your code, nothing is increasing, so `$count` never reaches 50.

Cheers.